# how to use sql to Check if a certain column value contains another certain column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, with 2 specific columns "log_number" and "message"

The "message" text value should contain the "log_number" value

Now I want to write a sql select to check if there is any bad rows which break the rules ! how can I do it ...

Comment: Any basic tutorial on SQL should make this clear.

Comment: I do have some basic sql tutorial, but I am sorry, I have no idea about this select...

Comment: I barely understand the question, but seems `instr()` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question... this will list the records for which the log_number string is not contained in your message string:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE instr(message, log_number) < 1;
```